# How to selectively initialize module-level objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask web app using SQLAlchemy. The database backing it in production is Postgres, but for the purpose of unit testing I would also like to be able to initialize it against SQLite.

I use `alembic` for database schema changes. For this reason, I've decided not to support SQLite for production, since making alembic support SQLite is more trouble than I want. However, I still want to be able to create the tables from scratch inside SQLite, for testing purposes; this doesn't invoke alembic, but just uses SQLAlchemy's `create_all()`.

I'm using declarative models, and in order to make alembic work better, I've set a naming convention for constraints as suggested in their documentation:

```
naming = {
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s",
}

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(naming_convention=naming))

class Model1(Base):
    ...
```

This works fine inside Postgres, but fails in SQLite; apparently the naming convention is somehow incompatible. (This may be related to the fact that some of my models have `Boolean` columns, which are apparently handled differently across the two engines.)

Since I don't actually need SQLite for production and couldn't use alembic there if I did, I'm inclined to simply drop the naming convention in that case and let it use default names when running tests. However, since this is all done at the module top level (and has to be, in order to use `Base` as a base class), I can't find a way to make this distinction. Ideally, I could set some kind of flag in the test suite before importing the models, which would cause that module to create `Base` with a default metadata rather than having the naming convention enabled. But I can't find a way to do this communication at import time.

How can I pass data in to control the creation of the declarative base at import time? Alternatively, is there a way to easily make SQLite work with the naming convention enabled?

Comment: what about use a config file?

Comment: Possible. Ideally I wouldn't have to change the file manually between running unit tests and running the full development server, but I could always make the test suite write out the file or something.

Comment: you may also detect code is running by a test runner, eg for pytest, check `PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST` environ: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pytest-current-test-environment-variable

Comment: If you aren't using SQLite in production, I would suggest actually testing with PostgreSQL instead, with [`testing.postgresql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testing.postgresql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this via environment variables. In the project module:

```
if os.environ.get('MYPROJECT_TESTING') == '1':
    Base = declarative_base()
else:
    Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(naming_convention=naming)
```

Then in the test harness:

```
os.environ['MYPROJECT_TESTING'] = '1'
import myproject
```

This works fine, though you have to make sure not to leave MYPROJECT_TESTING set in a shell environment, or ever set it in general other than automatically in the test scripts.